# How to select data from two tables together

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table which is split in two parts in SAP HANA (because of memory issue):

- "TEST"."TABLE_01"
- "TEST"."TABLE_02"

Now I want to select some columns from each table and make the remaining as a one table.

For example if `TABLE_01` and `TABLE_02` have 6 columns I want to select 3 columns from each and wanted to run the query for the whole table (which will be having 3 columns from `TABLE_01` and `TABLE_02`).

Say `TABLE_01` is like

```
id    student_name      class    subject   marks    rank
___  _______________    _____    _______   ______   _____
 1        john            10        phy      90       3 
 2        jean            11        che      80       6 
 3        oliver          10        phy      93       2 
 4        ryan            12        mat      99       1
```

like wise `TABLE_02` will have this data:

```
   id    student_name      class    subject   marks    rank
    ___  _______________    _____    _______   ______   _____
     1        tim            10        phy      93       3 
     2        jack           11        che      82       6 
     3        steve          10        phy      93       3 
     4        isaac          12        mat      99       9
```

So now I want to take `id`, `student_name` and `rank`.

```
 id    student_name          rank
___  _______________         _____   
 1        john                3 
 2        jean                6 
 3        oliver              2 
 4        ryan                1 
 1        tim                 3 
 2        jack                6 
 3        steve               3 
 4        isac                9
```

I want to run the query on this table. But how to join these two tables together? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Better to store all the data in single table as there isn't any meaning of storing similar data..even have same column names in multiple tables.

Comment: I cannot store all the table at once because I have out of memory issue while loading the table into memory

Comment: Then you have ask about how to resolve time out issue instead of splitting data in multiple tables. Just suggestion don't mind

Comment: Sorry, but why don't you simply partition the table? This gives you smaller memory allocation units and you still can deal with just one table.

Comment: I partitioned the table but still it was giving OOM error after a time when I import

Comment: You'd better ask a question how to import one table to avoid Out-Of-Memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using UNION operator:-

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Both UNION and UNION ALL concatenate the result of two different SQLs. They differ in the way they handle duplicates.

UNION performs a DISTINCT on the result set, eliminating any duplicate rows.
UNION ALL does not remove duplicates, and it therefore faster than UNION.

Example :-

```
select id, student_name, rank from table_01
union 
select id, student_name, rank from table_02
```

OR

```
select id, student_name, rank from table_01
union all
select id, student_name, rank from table_02
```

Comment: "UNION ALL" is better for performance and not to lose data from one of the tables. I already assume two tables have seperate users so a UNION is unneessary

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select id, student_name, rank from table_01
union all
select id, student_name, rank from table_02
```